Почему не работает макрос?
Мне нужно сделать фильтр по ячейке
Sub FilterTableByCellValue()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' Работаем с активным листом '
    
    Dim filterColumn As Integer
    filterColumn = 9 ' Столбец "Название" имеет номер 2 '
    
    Dim filterCellValue As Variant
    filterCellValue = ws.Range("B1").Value ' Значение для фильтрации из ячейки A1 '
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, filterColumn).End(xlUp).Row ' Последняя заполненная ячейка в столбце '
    
    ' Проверка на наличие данных в столбце '
    If lastRow > 0 Then
        ' Применение фильтра '
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, filterColumn), ws.Cells(lastRow, filterColumn)).AutoFilter _
            Field:=filterColumn, Criteria1:=filterCellValue
    Else
        MsgBox "Столбец '" & ws.Cells(1, filterColumn).Value & "' пустой."
    End If
End Sub

 ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, filterColumn), ws.Cells(lastRow, filterColumn)).AutoFilter _
            Field:=filterColumn, Criteria1:=filterCellValue

В этом месте ошибка
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
Run-time error'1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

Можете сделать еще, чтобы он одновременно фильтровал по всем  зеленым ячейкам и их столбцах.

Я исправил проблему, нужно было на все столбцы поставить фильтрацию
Можете сделать тогда фильтрацию по всем ячейкам

Почему не работает макрос? - Не работает, потому что нерабочий.... Каков  вопрос, такой и ответ. Как другие смогут найти ответ по такому "информативному" названию?!

–vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA, комментарий мой почитайте выше. А зачем нужен этот форум тогда ?
Ну наверное потому что человек не знает, как это исправить , и в чем ошибка.
Кстати, у вас очень классный никнейм,

Вы не поняли, о чем речь. Заголовок должен отражать проблему. Не Вы один можете искать решение этого вопроса.

Обычно полезно под макрорекордером проделать требуемое руками. несмотря на дебильность записанного кода, из него всегда можно выцедить чего полезного... а то и просто причесать его под требуемое.
